# What are the best steps to start programming with TDD with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, tdd

I want to start working with TDD but I don't know really where to start. We coding with .NET (C#/ASP.NET).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the questions [Why should I practice Test Driven Development and how should I start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303/why-should-i-practice-test-driven-development-and-how-should-i-start), [Moving existing code to Test Driven Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167079/moving-existing-code-to-test-driven-development), [What is unit testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383/what-is-unit-testing) and [What is TDD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260/what-is-tdd)

Comment: In addition to the above, read up on Uncle Bob and use TDD KATA as a means to test out the practiciality of TDD development. Don't try at work at first do some practice at home first on some little app or KATA and master the craft before trying to use it in a professional environment.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by reading up on TDD and why it's a good practice. As you read that, try to think about how the concepts apply to your own projects.

When I was learning TDD, it seemed simple at first, but it's such a paradigm shift that it forced me to change the way I thought about how my program would work. And I guess that's kind of the point. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is also lots of good information on the [Google Testing Blog](http://googletesting.blogspot.com/)

Answer (score 1):

There's a good book called [Test Driven Development in Microsoft .NET](http://www.microsoft.com/MSPress/books/6778.aspx) that you might check out. It is essentially the same as the classic [Test Driven Development by Example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321146530), but with the Microsoft platform in mind.

Comment: I'll definitively take a look at those books.