# Getting your head around other people's code

Tags: visualization, legacy, legacy-code

I'm occasionally unfortunate enough to have to make alterations to very old, <strike>poorly</strike> **not** documented and <strike>poorly</strike> **not** designed code.

It often takes a long time to make a simple change because there is not much structure to the existing code and I really have to read a lot of code before I have a feel for where things would be.

What I think would help a lot in cases like this is a tool that would allow one to visualise an overview of the code, and then maybe even drill down for more detail. I suspect such a tool would be very hard to get right, given that is trying to find structure where there is little or none.

I guess this is not really a question, but rather a musing. I should make it into a question - **What do others do to assist in getting their head around other peoples code, the good and the bad?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend [BOUML](http://bouml.free.fr/). It's a free UML modelling tool, which:

- is extremely fast (fastest UML tool ever created, check out [benchmarks](http://bouml.free.fr/benchmark.html)),
- has rock solid C++ import support,
- has great SVG export support, which is important, because viewing large graphs in vector format, which scales fast in e.g. Firefox, is very convenient (you can quickly switch between "birds eye" view and class detail view),
- is full featured, intensively developed (look at [development history](http://bouml.free.fr/historic.html), it's hard to believe that so fast progress is possible).

So: import your code into BOUML and view it there, or export to SVG and view it in Firefox.

Answer (score 4):

Hmm, this is a hard one, so much to say so little time ...

1) If you can run the code it makes life soooo much easier, breakpoints (especially conditional) break points are you friend.

2) A purists' approach would be to write a few unit tests, for known functionality, then refactor to improve code and understanding, then re-test. If things break, then create more unit tests - repeat until bored/old/moved to new project

3) ReSharper is good at showing where things are being used, what's calling a method for instance, it's static but a good start, and it helps with refactoring.

4) Many .net events are coded as public, and events can be a pain to debug at the best of times. Recode them to be private and use a property with add/remove. You can then use break point to see what is listening on an event.

BTW - I'm playing in the .Net space, and would love a tool to help do this kind of stuff, like Joel does anyone out there know of a good dynamic code reviewing tool?

Answer (score 4):

I have been asked to take ownership of some NASTY code in the past - both work and "play".

Most of the amateurs I took over code for had just sort of evolved the code to do what they needed over several iterations.  It was always a giant incestuous mess of library A calling B, calling back into A, calling C, calling B, etc.  A lot of the time they'd use threads and not a critical section was to be seen.

I found the best/only way to get a handle on the code was start at the OS entry point [main()] and build my own call stack diagram showing the call tree.  You don't really need to build a full tree at the outset.  Just trace through the section(s) you're working on at each stage and you'll get a good enough handle on things to be able to run with it.

To top it all off, use the biggest slice of dead tree you can find and a pen.  Laying it all out in front of you so you don't have to jump back and forward on screens or pages makes life so much simpler.

EDIT:  There's a lot of talk about coding standards... they will just make poor code look consistent with good code (and usually be harder to spot).  Coding standards don't always make maintaining code easier.

Answer (score 3):

I do this on a regular basis. And have developed some tools and tricks.

- Try to get a general overview (object diagram or other).
- Document your findings.
- Test your assumptions (especially for vague code).

The problem with this is that on most companies you are appreciated by result. That's why some programmers write poor code fast and move on to a different project. So you are left with the garbage, and your boss compares your sluggish progress with the quick and dirtu guy. (Luckily my current employer is different).

Answer (score 2):

I generally use UML sequence diagrams of various key ways that the component is used.  I don't know of any tools that can generate them automatically, but many UML tools such as BoUML and EA Sparx can create classes/operations from source code which saves some typing.

Comment: I never use UML to design new code, but I also find it extremely useful in visualizing the class hierarchies and relationships of legacy systems written by other people when I have to take over something.

Answer (score 2):

The definitive text on this situation is Michael Feathers' Working Effectively with Legacy Code. As [S. Lott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10661/s-lott) says get some unit tests in to establish behaviour of the lagacy code. Once you have those in you can begin to refactor. There seems to be a sample chapter [available](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/WorkingEffectivelyWithLegacyCode.pdf) on the Object Mentor website.

Answer (score 1):

See [Unit Testing Legacy ASP.NET Webforms Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342693/unit-testing-legacy-web-apps) for advice on getting a grip on legacy apps via unit testing.

There are many similar questions and answers.  Here's the search https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=unit+test+legacy

The point is that getting your head around legacy is probably easiest if you are writing unit tests for that legacy.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had great luck with tools to automate the review of poorly documented/executed code, cause a confusing/badly designed program generally translates to a less than useful model. It's not exciting or immediately rewarding, but I've had the best results with picking a spot and following the program execution line by line, documenting and adding comments as I go, and refactoring where applicable.

Comment: This is the only way of following especially if execution paths are broken by some weird reflection mechanism that delegates method invocation to a cloud of objects

Answer (score 1):

a good IDE (EMACS or Eclipse) could help in many cases. Also on a UNIX-platform, there are some tools for crossreferencing (etags, ctags) or checking (lint) or gcc with many many warning options turned on.

First, before trying to comprehend a function/method, i would refactor it a bit to fit your coding conventions (spaces, braces, indentation) and remove most of the comments if they seem to be wrong.

Then I would refactor and comment the parts you understood, and try to find/grep those parts over the whole source tree and refactor them there also.

Over the time, you get a nicer code, you like to work with.

Answer (score 1):

I personally do a lot of drawing of diagrams, and figuring out the bones of the structure.

The fad de jour (and possibly quite rightly) has got me writing unit tests to test my assertions, and build up a safety net for changes I make to the system.

Once I get to a point where I'm comfortable enought knowing what the system does, I'll take a stab at fixing bugs in the sanest way possible, and hope my safety nets neared completion.

That's just me, however. ;)

Answer (score 1):

i have actuaally been using the refactoring features of ReSharper to help m get a handle on a bunch of projects that i inherited recently. So, to figure out another programmer's very poorly structured, undocumented code, i actually start by refactoring it.

Cleaning up the code, renaming methods, classes and namespaces properly, extracting methods are all structural changes that can shed light on what a piece of code is supposed to do. It might sound counterintuitive to refactor code that you don't "know" but trut me, ReSharper really allows you to do this. Take for example the issue of red herring dead code. You see a method in a class or perhaps a strangely named variable. You can start by trying to lookup usages or, ungh, do a text search, but ReSharper will actually detect dead code and color it gray. As soon as you open a file you see in gray and with scroll bar flags what would have in the past been confusing red herrings.

There are dozens of other tricks and probably a number of other tools that can do similar things but i am a ReSharper junky.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Get to know the software intimately from a user's point of view.  A lot can be learnt about the underlying structure by studying and interacting with the user interface(s).

Answer (score 1):

- Printouts
- Whiteboards
- Lots of notepaper
- Lots of Starbucks

Being able to scribble all over the poor thing is the most useful method for me.  Usually I turn up a lot of "huh, that's funny..." while trying to make basic code structure diagrams that turns out to be more useful than the diagrams themselves in the end.  Automated tools are probably more helpful than I give them credit for, but the value of finding those funny bits exceeds the value of rapidly generated diagrams for me.

For diagrams, I look for mostly where the data is going.  Where does it come in, where does it end up, and what does it go through on the way.  Generally what happens to the data seems to give a good impression of the overall layout, and some bones to come back to if I'm rewriting.

Answer (score 1):

When I'm working on legacy code, I don't attempt to understand the entire system. That would result in complexity overload and subsequent brain explosion.

Rather, I take one single feature of the system and try to understand completely how it works, from end to end. I will generally debug into the code, starting from the point in the UI code where I can find the specific functionality (since this is usually the only thing I'll be able to find at first). Then I will perform some action in the GUI, and drill down in the code all the way down into the database and then back up. This usually results in a complete understanding of at least one feature of the system, and sometimes gives insight into other parts of the system as well.

Once I understand what functions are being called and what stored procedures, tables, and views are involved, I then do a search through the code to find out what other parts of the application rely on these same functions/procs. This is how I find out if a change I'm going to make will break anything else in the system.

It can also sometimes be useful to attempt to make diagrams of the database and/or code structure, but sometimes it's just so bad or so insanely complex that it's better to ignore the system as a whole and just focus on the part that you need to change.

Answer (score 1):

My big problem is that I (currently) have very large systems to understand in a fairly short space of time (I pity contract developers on this point) and don't have a lot of experience doing this (having previously been fortunate enough to be the one designing from the ground up.)

One method I use is to try to understand the meaning of the naming of variables, methods, classes, etc.  This is useful because it (hopefully increasingly) embeds a high-level view of a train of thought from an atomic level.

I say this because typically developers will name their elements (with what they believe are) meaningfully and providing insight into their intended function. This is flawed, admittedly, if the developer has a defective understanding of their program, the terminology or (often the case, imho) is trying to sound clever. How many developers have seen keywords or class names and only then looked up the term in the dictionary, for the first time?

Comment: I'd also like to say that, although I've not tried it, developing applications (this may only pertain to web apps) as essentially distributed or service oriented may well lead to easier to understand architectures - a small app pulling others together!

Answer (score 0):

It's all about the standards and coding rules your company is using.

if everyone codes in different style, then it's hard to maintain other programmer code and etc, if you decide what standard you'll use have some rules, everything will be fine :) Note: that you don't have to make a lot of rules, because people should have possibility to code in style they like, otherwise you can be very surprised.