# What is the "garbage adapter pattern"?

Tags: testing, design-patterns, legacy, adapter

Back in 2009, [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342693/unit-testing-legacy-asp-net-webforms-legacy-applications/342710#342710) mentioned the "garbage adapter pattern", in reference to what happens when you try and add tests to a legacy code base that you are not allowed to radically modify.  I was unable to find any other mentions of this phrase.  Does any have some guesses as to what it was intended to refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such actual coding pattern at all; the person answering just means someone has written code to 'adapt' some 'garbage' code to something usable.

Comment: ah: they mean the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern applied to garbage (i.e. the legacy code).

Comment: @JesseW - I hadn't considered it that way, but that's exactly right, yes!