# How to do unit testing using PHPUnit in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, phpunit

How we can do PHPUnit testing in wordpress website ? Including theme and plugin everything.

I have setup the phpunit and included **wp-load.php** file to get all functions and classes access.

Is this correct way ? or There is any better way of doing the Unit Testing in wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/testing/automated-testing/phpunit/ ? When writing unit testing you should ask yourself: What do i want this function to do? and then write the test based on that.

To answer your question if there is a correct way to write unit testing, I think it's not. its just a matter on how smart you write your tests. Go have a look at [New to unit testing, how to write great tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258733/new-to-unit-testing-how-to-write-great-tests) for some inspiration. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for making it clear. I think i am on right track, i have written test cases for many webapps, I was just curious about standards.