# How to write Junit for java

Tags: junit4

I am very new to junit and java. kindly let me know how write the junit for this code.

```
void Abc(Objsect o) {
    Attr[] attrd= o.changeAttr();
    if (attrd.length > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < attrd.length; i++) {
            if (attrd[i].toString().contains(PropertyMessage.fsc_pra)) {
                ifModified = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not returning anything or changing Objsect o, so this function does nothing? Please consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258733/new-to-unit-testing-how-to-write-great-tests).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New to unit testing, how to write great tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258733/new-to-unit-testing-how-to-write-great-tests)

Comment: Objsect is a hashmap @Frieder